# Oracle SOA Suite: One entry per adapter instance in the adapters_config.xml?

Tags: soa, jca, oracle-soa

I plan to get a Oracle SOA Suite Implementation Specialist (1z0-478)
While practicing with example question I encountered a question make me confused:

*Each JCA adapter has a single deployment listed in the WLS Console. Identify two accurate descriptions about managing multiple instances of each adapter in the runtime.

A. Instance configuration in the SOA Suite deployment plan

B. JCA tiles for each adapter instance

C. Adapter connection factories specified in the WLS Console

D. One entry per adapter instance in the adapters_config.xml file*D

Answers are: A, D

But I can't find any file named adapters_config.xml?
And I don't know what is entry in here?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SOA 11g most of the configurations files /common xsd‘s are stored in MDS.

All the configurations files available in MDS are read only; the configurable values can be changed through EM console or WLST script etc.

in MDS you can see adapters_config.xml under soa/configuration/default folder under SOA folder in MDS.

following is the sample: